How do I cause a form submit on a webpage?
I use a website with a very simple form (A single text entry box) regularly. On desktop and laptop, I put type my text and press enter and the form submits.
On Andriod with gboard I can't seem to press enter, or even tab to the submit button.
The right side of my gboard is p l backspace and this green button that looks like it should tab but doesn't do anything after the first time.  The first time I've loaded the page it works, but not again.
What I've been doing is scrolling sideways over to the submit button and tap on it.
This is the second or third phone I've had that this happens on.
Phones: Pixel 3, Samsung Galaxy A20, Pixel 8.
All this was in Chrome.
I've tried exploring gboard to see if there was some setting to make that green button do something, but I haven't been able to find it.

I think that depends on the used html code. But then it would be a development question that should be posted on stackoverflow.com

I can look at the HTML and read it.  But I didn't develop the site I'm using.  I'm just trying to use a website that works fine on desktop (and many phones?) but doesn't on mine, and I'm trying to get it to work.

The HTML code defines how form works. Take e.g. this sample form. If you are in "First name" and press "return" on the keyboard focus switches to "Last name" and if you again press return the  form is submitted/executed.

Yes, that works there.  The green button doesn't do anything on the particular form I'm using.  I'm asking is there some way to cause the form to submit, similar to how pressing enter on the desktop does?

I don't think I can answer your question without having seen the form myself. As I wrote the reason for this behavior is most likely the HTML code. The web browser and GBoard behave as the web developer has defined it. May be the page wasn't tested on Android or the web developer made a mistake, but that are only guesses. Defects if a web page can not be corrected in client side in a simple way (some web browser or plugins may allow to modify page data but that requires web dev skills).
